# Maximum flow with edge demands: can't understand the example of transition to transformed graph in the lecture notes

Tags: graphs, network-flow, max-cut

TL;DR:
There're [lecture notes](http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/2009/notes/18-maxflowext.pdf) about a very simple reduction from "maximum flow with edge demands problem to the maximum flow problem. But I can't get the new capacities at the picture:
[image: graph]

E.g., look at the diagonal: 15 - 0 = 14 (?). From my point of view there're a lot of off-by-one errors.

Answer (score 1):

Those are just typos, as you can confirm by reading the general construction on the previous page ("Intuitively, we construct $G'$ by ...") and applying it to the flow network on the left.  Yes, there are multiple off-by-one errors.  It happens. Pobody's nerfect.

Incidentally, you might want to read the latest version of his notes, available from http://web.engr.illinois.edu/~jeffe/teaching/algorithms/, rather than the 2009 version you're reading right now (though this particular typo is still present).